# how to update openssl module which is associated with ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, openssl

Is it possible to update the openssl module which is associated with ruby on Windows?

If yes, how?

Following are the gem details installed on my Windows:

> gem -v

```
1.8.1.6
```

> ruby --version

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
```

> ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'

```
OpenSSL 1.0.0k 5 Feb 2013
```

Comment: Side note: You should update your Ruby version, its too dated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag and drop the respective OpenSSL DLL files `[libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll]` into the Ruby bin folder, *replacing the old versions*, and it will use those DLLs as a replacement.

However `OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION` is set at compile time and will not reflect the version of the libraries you may be using. To check the version you would have to access the library directly from Ruby and ask it.

For `OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION` to reflect the version you're using you will have to recompile Ruby using that version.

The [OpenKnapsack Project](https://bintray.com/oneclick/OpenKnapsack) has compiled versions of the binaries you can use. Alternatively, you can compile your own.

Since Ruby 1.9.3 has reached it's **End of Life** date, I can't guarantee any of the new OpenSSL versions will actually work with it.

Comment: What about the openssl.so file? Can that remain same?

Comment: In MOST cases yes. There are probably some cases that I can't think of where it wouldn't work.